# Can't save the value of JavaScript prompt() function

Tags: javascript, html, prompt

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm building a very basic battleship program, but I've noticed that the prompt() function doesn't seem to bring up a dialog box if I try to save it's value to a variable. Here's my code:

```
var location1 = 3;
var location2 = 4;
var location3 = 5;


var hits = 0;
var guesses = 0;
var guess;

var isSunk = false;


while (isSunk == false){
guess = prompt("Ready, aim, fire! Enter a number 0-6");
if (guess < 0 || > 6){
    alert("PLease enter a valid cell number!");
}
else{
    guesses = guesses + 1;

    if (guess == location1 || guess == location2 || guess == location3){
        alert("Hit!");
        hits = hits + 1;
        if (hits == 3){
            isSunk = true;
            alert("You sank my battleship!");
        }
        else{
            alert("Miss!");
        }
    }
}
}
var stats = "You took " + guesses + " guesses to sink the battleship, " + "which means your shooting accuracy was " + (3/guesses);
alert(stats);
```

Now, the reason that I think my prompt not appearing when I load the browser is due to the fact that I'm trying to set the value of the prompt to the variable guess is because the following code executes without issue:

```
 var location1 = 3;
 var location2 = 4;
 var location3 = 5;

 var hits = 0;
 var guesses = 0;
 var guess;

 var isSunk = false;


 while (isSunk == false){
   prompt("Ready, aim, fire! Enter a number 0-6");
   isSunk = true;
}
var stats = "You took " + guesses + " guesses to sink the battleship, " + "which means your shooting accuracy was " + (3/guesses);
alert(stats);
```

Can someone help me understand what the issue with my code is please? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: There's a typo in the conditional: `if (guess < 0 || > 6){`. The correct version would be `if (guess < 0 || guess > 6){`. Given a syntax error like that, the rest of the script won't run. Your [JavaScript console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) should have an error message pointing you to the syntax error.

Comment: You need to learn to look in the debug console for script errors.  That will show you exactly when you've made an error in your code that causes an exception and stops execution.  Any times you are confused about why something isn't working, look first in the debug console for errors.

Answer (score 3):

You are using [prompt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) correctly.
The problem is in the line below :
`if (guess < 0 || > 6) {`
should be
`if (guess < 0 || guess > 6){`

This error was stopping the JS before `prompt()` was called.
In the future, you should use the browser console to debug your code. You would have seen this error.
If you use Firefox, you can open it with `Ctrl+Shift+K`. With Chrome it's `Ctrl+Shift+J`.

When you will have resolved this issue, you will see that the rest of the code has no syntax error but is not doing exactly the right thing (for example I can hit the same location several times). Logic errors are not as easy to fix (you have no debugger to help you). So... good luck !
Well, don't worry in your case it won't be hard to fix.

Comment: How can I open the console using Safari? I know that when I don't have a dialog pop up I can right click and choose "Inspect Element," and I can reach the console in that manner. But when I have a dialog pop up, I'm unable to reach the console in that manner.

Comment: @Kiyana Ctrl+Shift+C according to : http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/77337 (I don't use Safari myself)

Answer (score 1):

+1 to the above comment.

Furthermore Kiyana, when you run your code, you'll notice that as long as the user's input is not <0 or >6, the alert("Hit!") and the alert("Miss!") are both appearing.

This has to do with the ordering of your code:

```
if (guess == location1 || guess == location2 || guess == location3){
    alert("Hit!");
    hits = hits + 1;
    if (hits == 3){
        isSunk = true;
        alert("You sank my battleship!");
    }
    else{
        alert("Miss!");
    }
}
```

Here is the order in which you want the above code to appear.

Pseudo Code:

1. If user's guess is 3, 4, or 5 (location1, location2, or location3), then we want to alert a "Hit"
2. Then, add 1 counter to the hit variable (hit = hit + 1)
3. ELSE - then we want to alert a "Miss."
4. **After this guess is evaluated**, we want to check to see if the hit counter has reached 3.

a) If it hasn't, then we loop back through all the code.

b) If it has, then we want to make isSunk equal to true (to stop the loop) and alert a "You sank my battleship!"

The code should look like this:

```
var location1 = 3;
var location2 = 4;
var location3 = 5;


var hits = 0;
var guesses = 0;
var guess;

var isSunk = false;


while (isSunk === false){
guess = prompt("Ready, aim, fire! Enter a number 0-6");

if (guess < 0 || guess > 6){
    alert("Please enter a valid cell number!");
} else{
    guesses = guesses + 1;

if (guess == location1 || guess == location2 || guess == location3){
    alert("Hit!");
    hits = hits + 1;
    }else{
        alert("Miss!");
    }
    if (hits == 3){
        isSunk = true;
        alert("You sank my battleship!");
    }
}
}
var stats = "You took " + guesses + " guesses to sink the battleship, " +  "which means your shooting accuracy was " + (3/guesses);
alert(stats);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!! I opted to write my conditional statements in a slightly different order, and I wanted to see if this works as well:
`code`
while (isSunk == false){
 guess = prompt("Ready, aim, fire! Enter a number 0-6");
 if (guess < 0 || guess > 6){
  alert("PLease enter a valid cell number!");
 }
 else{
  guesses = guesses +1;
  if (guess == location1 || guess == location2 || guess == location3){
   alert("Hit!");
   hits = hits + 1;
   if (hits == 3){
    isSunk = true;
    alert("You sank my battleship!");
   }
  }
  else{
   alert("Miss!");
  }
 }
}
`code`

Comment: Forgive me, I'm not entirely certain how to properly format code within a comment!!